# URLRequest with headers in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

Im relatively new to to Swift and I'm having trouble pulling some JSON from an API with the swift native URLRequest - this is in a playground. I've tested the API endpoint and it returns the data just fine in Postman

Here is my code:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play
import Foundation
import XCPlayground
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

let urlString = "http://example.test/industry"
let session = URLSession.shared
let url = URL(string: urlString)!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)

request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
    if let responseData = response
    {
        do{
            /*let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: [])
             print(json)*/
        }catch{
            print("Could not serialize")
        }
    }
})
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

What am I doing wrong here? I need to send headers to request JSON from my endpoint.

Comment: You have to say `if let responseData = data` instead of `... = response` and send the datatask with the `resume()` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to add `.resume()` after `dataTask{...}`.

As a result, it would look like this:

```
session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
    if let data = data{
        do{
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
            print(json)
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

}).resume
```

Comment: Thanks, so now I want to do the following `let data = try Data(contentsOf: responseData)` so I can start to serialise the JSON but I get `Cannot convert value of type 'Data' to expected argument type 'URL'` why is this?

Comment: @iLC you should look at the documentation for the function you're unsure about... `Data(contentsOf:)` clearly tells you that it expects a local `URL`. What you actually need is `if let data = data{do{let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) print(json)} catch {print(error)}}`

Comment: Thanks that makes much more sense, I wanted to use Alamo but it was being awkward with Playground, thanks for your help david.